# Using sandboxed pages in chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Manifest version 2 of chrome extensions will no longer support use of **eval** or **new Function** on regular extension pages. My chrome extension uses a UI Framework (Kendo UI) on the options page that makes use of these mechanisms and therefore I'm looking for a solution.

According to [this session](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/208/) from IO 2012 the idea is to put the corresponding page into a sandbox and load it into the extension via an iframe.

Here is a simplified example what I'm trying to do: https://gist.github.com/3058943

manifest.json:

```
{
 "name": "Sandbox test",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "options_page": "main.html",
 "sandbox": {
    "pages": [ "index.html" ]
  }
}
```

main.html:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="index.html" ></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Inside the sandbox</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I load the options page in this example, I'm getting the error message:

> Denying load of chrome-extension://fahdnpkbgfjkocogbjlljfbhnljcehoh/index.html. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by web pages.

I don't think that each sandboxed page is also supposed to be a web_accessible_resources.
But even when I try to define the sandboxed pages also as web_accessible_resources in the manifest file, then the sandboxed page gets loaded but use of **new Function** inside the iframe is still blocked.

Comment: Problem solved in dev channel version 21.0.1180.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above described error message occurs on Chrome 20.0.1132.47.

I tested with the dev channel version 21.0.1180.15 and here the sandboxed iframe loads without problems.

Comment: Sandboxed iframes are supported in Chrome 21 and later (currently in the dev channel). You can see that the stable channel (Chrome 20) documentation does not mention them: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html, but the dev channel one does: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/manifest.html